# Refresh part of a form not the whole thing

Tags: vb.net, refresh

Basically I need the code that refreshes a part of the form, not the whole thing.

I use visual basic and I often make very simple games. I often have a *Player* or different objects which move around, and since I'm not publishing my code I don't add textures. Instead I set up a bunch of variables which hold the `location` and `width` of the *Player* and then use `e.graphics.FillRectangle`... etc, and that works fine, and say I move it when I press a key but nothing happens, so I have to write `Refresh()`, which works, it moves!

Only problem is when there are lots of objects, like 50+, every time the program runs the `Refresh()` line of code the whole `form` goes **white for a millisecond**, and normally I am refreshing all the time because things are moving all the time and the form just becomes an epilepsy nightmare.

I know what I need to do, I only need to `refresh` a small part of the whole form, I just don't know how to.

Comment: if the rect doesnt move as expected, you may have drawn your things incorrectly or this is an XY problem.  *very* hard to say with no code.  See: [Ask]

Comment: The [`Invalidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method has options for the parameters.

Comment: If you move something and just paint where it goes it will leave an empty/undrawn area where it left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to do it

You can use the `Invalidate` method to achieve what you want.

#### What is invalidate

To better understand the following code you simply need to know what `Invalidate` does. Simply put, it **invalidates** the entire `control` you have selected and forces it to **redraw** itself.

#### Knowing what to invalidate

**Option 1**

The easiest way to do this would be the following :

```
Me.Invalidate(New Region(New Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100)))
```

By doing this you are doing a `invalidate` (causing a repaint) on a `100 width` and `100 height` at the position  `(10,10)` of your form.

**Option 2**

If option 1 does not do what you want I would suggest naming your `rectangles` with an `Increment` therefor having access to them by name such as `MyRectange1.Invalidate()`, `MyRectangle2.Invalidate()`and so on (most likely in a loop).

**Option 3**

If you don't know specificly which `rectangle` to refresh and don't want to specify a `region` you could separate your screen in let's say 4 parts (which would be containers such as a panel). You could then do something like this : `panelBottomLeft.Invalidate()`.

Or like this :

```
    For Each ControlToRefresh In panelBottomLeft.Controls
        ControlToRefresh.Invalidate()
    Next
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful and worked perfectly, thanks micbobo.